# Is it ok to store a Fragment instance as a member of my Activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Activity I have a `FrameLayout` that covers the entire screen, but is empty at startup. When the user taps a button, a `Fragment` is displayed in the `FrameLayout` using this code:

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.grow_from_bottom_left, R.anim.stay);
transaction.replace(R.id.overlayLayout, new MyFragment(), MyFragment.TAG);
transaction.commit();
```

As you can see, I'm creating a new `MyFragment` every time the user taps the button (the fragment covers the button, and is removed when tapping back using `transaction.remove()`).

I'm thinking that it's probably not good for performance to always create a new fragment, so instead I wanted to create it once and then just show/hide it in the `FrameLayout`. My first thought was to simply store it as a member in my activity and reuse the same instance:

```
MyFragment mMyFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMyFragment = new MyFragment();
}
```

Is this the proper way to handle this scenario?

Or should I be using the `SupportFragmentManager` to store the fragment? I tried using it, but then my fragment doesn't display when I use it in `transaction.replace()`, even though I can find the fragment perfectly fine using `findFragmentByTag()`... I'm suspecting it's because I don't add it to a view when I first create it - but I don't want to add it to a view until the user taps the button.

Comment: Create it as new every time cause in this case it will be loaded as new not with the previous state . Use `findFragmentByTag()` or `findFragmentById()` to access it .

Comment: @ADM But what if I don't mind having the state saved? It's basically just showing a list of items from a database using a `CursorLoader`.

Comment: Well if same data will be loaded each time and no state is saving then you can use same instance to add in transaction.